# barplot in R 3.1.1

Tags: r, bar-chart

even if I am getting used to R I am still new with it and I hope that someone can help me deal with this task ...I have tried to look for some previous topics but I couldn't find what I was looking for, so here I am hoping for some help.

I am trying to  draw my bar plot but I am not having much luck on some of the settings so I hope someone could help. I am using R 3.1.1 on my mac OS 10.9.4.

my table look like this:

```
family      area1 area2 area3 area4 area5 area6 

   A        15    20    500  200   17    26 

   B        170   520    26   13   100    70 

   C        35    250    358   128   88    26

   D        95    375    289   156  169    356

   E        425   177    136   144   285    70
```

since I have the file save it as a csv I am doing this steps:

```
fam <- read.csv ("family_per_area_count.csv", sep =";", header = T)
```

I am converting the file as a matrix

```
fam.mat <- as.matrix(fam_1, ncol = 6, byrow = T)
```

then I assign row names and col names

```
rownames(fam.mat) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") 
colnames(fam.mat) <- c("area1", "area2", "area3", "area4", "area5", "area6")
```

then  I am simply running the bar plot command as

```
barplot(fam.mat, beside = T, col = rainbow(ncol(fam.mat)))
```

but I am missing most of the labels for the x axis and the plot seems to be pressed together.

I also tried to run the cumulative bar plot using this command

```
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 7.1), xpd = TRUE)

prop <- prop.table(data_mat, margin = 2)

barplot(data_mat, col = rainbow(length(rownames(data_mat))), width = 3)

legend("topright", inset = c(-0.25, 0), fill = rainbow(length(rownames(data_mat))), 
       legend = rownames(data_mat))
```

but the legend colours don't match the data and again my x-axis seems out of center. I have tried to transpose the matrix but still no luck.

Can anyone make any suggestion?

Thank you so much in advance

F.

Comment: You say you are "trying to use ggplot2" but then proceed to show code, which only uses base graphics.

Comment: mmm ...that's me not being good with R but on all the tutorial that I looked online bar plot was part of the ggplot2 package

Comment: Function `barplot()` is not part of package `ggplot2`

Comment: You can make barplots with ggplot2 and you can produce them with base graphics. Since both approaches are very different, you either need to indicate a preferance or no preference.

Comment: ok thanks for the informations, I was only following what I found as tutorials, and the one I found load ggplot2, hence my confusion. I will only like to been able to represent my data properly if anyone have any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
DF <- read.table(text="family      area1 area2 area3 area4 area5 area6 

   A        15    20    500  200   17    26 

                 B        170   520    26   13   100    70 

                 C        35    250    358   128   88    26

                 D        95    375    289   156  169    356

                 E        425   177    136   144   285    70", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(DF, id.var="family")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=family, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Study ggplot2 documentation and tutorials to learn how to customise the plot.

Comment: THANK YOU! I will be giving it a try and work it from here, I was just lost. ^_^